# Вопрос о разряде прилагательного

Tags: прилагательные

Живая музыка - здесь качественное прилагательное или относительное, которое появилось из качественного?

Answer (score 1):

1. Прилагательное ***живой*** — многозначное слово (в словаре указано 7 значений). В основном это **относительное** прилагательное, соотнесённое со словами «жизнь, жить». Но встречаются и **качественные** прилагательные, если у них есть соответствующие синонимы: 3. Полный жизненных сил; жизнерадостный. Ж. ребёнок. Ж-ая натура. Ж. темперамент. 6. Деятельный, активно проявляющийся; сильно ощущаемый. Ж-ое любопытство. Ж. интерес.
2. ***Живая музыка*** – это терминологическое сочетание, в состав которого входит **относительное** прилагательное, то есть это музыка, исполняемая непосредственно **живыми людьми** (музыкантами), а не воспроизводимая в записи.

«Существуют два основных вида слышимой нами музыки — живая (исполняемая музыкантами) и неживая (воспроизводимая с носителя). Исполнение музыки живым звуком и воспроизведение записи — два противоположных полюса. Между ними существуют промежуточные варианты: живое исполнение, частично живое исполнение, исполнение под фонограмму».

http://artmaestro.ru/tgxlux/25-sal-ki.html